# Regex reverse lookup in xsl matches function

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to identify phone numbers that do not match certain criteria. Among oher things, I want to match international numbers that are not French (ie not +33 nor 0033). I have a regex that uses a reverse lookup (ie "?!") to say "not 33" which works when I test it alone. However when I try to use it in an xsl stylesheet I get an error "Invalid regular expression FORX0002".

Here is the part of my Regex that is causing me problems

`^((\+|00)(?!33)[1-9]\d{0,2})\D?(\d\D?){9,14}$`

Simplified stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="fo fn xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root class="object">
            <contacts class="array">
                <xsl:for-each select="//row">
                    <row>
                        <xsl:if test="not(matches(., '^((\+|00)(?!33)[1-9]\d{0,2})\D?(\d\D?){9,14}$'))">
                            <Business_Phone>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </Business_Phone>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </contacts>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <Identifier>02</Identifier>
        <Name>John Doe</Name>
        <Business_Phone>+34 67.89</Business_Phone>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Identifier>03</Identifier>
        <Name>Jim Doe</Name>
        <Business_Phone>+33 123 456 789</Business_Phone>
    </row>
</root>
```

With this sample I am expecting to get:

```
<root class="object">
    <contacts class="array">
        <row>
            <Identifier class="string">02</Identifier>
            <Business_Phone>+34 67.89</Business_Phone>
        </row>
    </contacts>
</root>
```

Is there a syntax I can use to make this work?
Many thanks

Comment: Which XSLT 2 processor is that? With Saxon I think you might be able to switch to the regular expression support of the underlying platform like Java or .NET by using a flags argument of `;j` or `;n` where hopefully the negative lookahead is supported.

Comment: So with Saxon Java you could use `<xsl:copy-of select="//row[matches(Business_Phone, '^((\+|00)(?!33)\s*[1-9]\d{0,2})\D?(\d\D?){5,14}$', ';j')]"/>` (I shortened the quantifier `{9,14}` in your pattern as I don't see how `+34 67.89` would match at least nine characters at the end.